# Night shift employees break time creating multiple records

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am trying to make a report that calculates the break time of night shift employees.But have a problem. let's say the night shift timings are from 9PM till 6AM next morning. According to the program the attendance detail is as below if employee does not take a break which is easy to calculate the duration of the work difference of checkout1 and checkout2

```
emp_num   checkin1                   checkout1                   
81111     2014-08-21 21:38:06.000    2014-08-22 06:00:10.000
```

When he takes a break at 2AM in the shift  a new record is created. Since there is multiple records i am not able to calculate the duration of work .please help

```
emp_num   checkin1                   checkout1                   
81111     2014-08-21 21:38:06.000    2014-08-22 02:00:10.000        
81111     2014-08-22 02:30:00.000    2014-08-22 06:00:10.000
```

Comment: Subtract a few hours from the start time to get both rows starting on the same date and group by that. Using Standard SQL: `cast(checkin - interval '6' hours as date)`

Comment: i am looking for a crystal report solution where employee  with hour(first_in) >=21(9PM) the duration should be difference of checkin of first record and checkout of second record .similarly break time difference should be checkout of first record and checkin of second record

Answer (score 0):

I have created a temporary table and uploaded your data.

```
create table #employee (EmpID int, CheckIn Datetime, CheckOut Datetime, HoursWorked time)
```

Then I inserted the data as shown below.

```
EmpID   CheckIn                    CheckOut
1       2014-08-21 21:38:06.000    2014-08-22 06:00:10.000    
2       2014-08-21 21:38:06.000    2014-08-22 02:00:10.000        
2       2014-08-22 02:30:00.000    2014-08-22 06:00:10.000
```

I updated HoursWorked column as

```
update #employee set HoursWorked = CheckOut - CheckIn
```

Below select statement gives the required output.

```
SELECT EmpID,SUM(DATEPART(HOUR,hoursworked))AS HoursWorked, 
            SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE,hoursworked))AS MinutesWorked,
            SUM(DATEPART(SECOND,hoursworked))AS SecondsWorked FROM #employee
GROUP BY EmpID

EmpID   HoursWorked  MinutesWorked  SecondsWorked
1       8            22             4
2       7            52             14
```

Let me know if there are any mistakes or shortcuts. Subtacting working hours from 9 gives you the break time.

Comment: Madhukar... how will i calculate the break time from 2 am till 2:30 am?